# jQuery dialog is not displaying correctly in Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, dialog

I have a strange issue displaying a jQuery dialog.  On my dev PC, it seems to work fine.  I get something like the following

http://bc.coverstar.com/images/tempimages/Dialog-correct.jpg

However, if I run it on any of our production PC's, it shows like this:

http://bc.coverstar.com/images/tempimages/Dialog-incorrect.jpg

Any ideas on what might be causing this?

Note: These are both running off of the same URL.

Comment: Checked the console for errors? CSS not loading perhaps? We'll need some code an an example illustrating the problem.

Comment: Can you post the code related to this? Also, are the browser versions the same?

Comment: Ah!  The console showed that http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.7/themes/start/jquery-ui.css is blocked.  That makes sense.  My Dev PC has unlimited access, while production has corporate blocking.

Comment: @Scottie - if thats the case, add the css manually to your solution instead of using the online reference.

Comment: j08691, add your comment as an answer and I'll mark you as the correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checked the console for errors? CSS not loading perhaps? It would appear that something is not being loaded and is perhaps blocked on your production machine.

Answer (score 1):

jQquery uses stylesheets or themes for applying styles to dialog. It seems that you are probably using the jQuery "Redmond" theme and check if you have given link in head section of your document in production-pc.